# java.lang.NullPointerException in servlet error 500

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, dispatcher

When I run my Servlet I get this error:
java.lang.NullPointerException please i tried many solutions but it didn't work it's simple code

```
public LoginServlett() {
    super();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


    String name = request.getParameter("UserName");
    String pass = request.getParameter("Password"); 

    RequestDispatcher d=null;

    if (name.contentEquals("Gestionnaire") && pass.contentEquals("1234")) {
         HttpSession session;
         session =request.getSession(true );
          d =request.getRequestDispatcher("/EspaceGestionnaire.html");
         session. setAttribute("NomSauvegardé" ,name);
    }

    else {
         d = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Authentification.html");
        d.forward(request, response);

    } 
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}
```

}

Comment: At what point is it complaining about a NPE? The log should tell you. My guess is that one of those files doesn't exist

Comment: NullPointerException is so common and JEE machinery is so big, it could be anything. Try to dig a bit deeper, experiment with the code and then post full stack trace.

Comment: The log files existes LoginServlett in C:\Users\pc\JEE-workspace\AgenceLocations\build\classes\LoginServlett.class  the others /EspaceGestionnaire &/Authentification  in C:\Users\pc\JEE-workspace\AgenceLocations\WebContent

Answer (score 0):

A NPE will be thrown from the code if the Username and Password parameters are not set. If they are not set then the `user` and `pass` variables will be null, and when the contentEquals methods are called on them a NPE will be thrown as a result.

A way to do this would be to reverse the equality checks so the operation is called on string you want to check:

```
if ("Gestionnaire".contentEquals(name) && "1234".contentEquals(pass)) {
```

which will do what your code intends without throwing a NPE.

Although if you are sending passwords over the internet it is better to use POST than GET. For Java EE security there is also the new security API (https://javaee.github.io/security-spec/)